# How to understand the conversion rule when a "pointer to an object type" compares for eqality with a "pointer to a void"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

[n1570 6.5.9.5 (Equality operators)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9) says:

> 5 ......If one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.

If "former" is "latter" are "pointer to object type" and "pointer to a void", then it means, after the conversion, the compare happens on two `void*`s, which according to 6.5.9.2, is undefined:

> 2.One of the following shall hold:
>
> both operands have arithmetic type;
>
> both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
>
> one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
>
> one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Is this an language defect in N1570?

Comment: If both pointers are (or have been converted to) `void *` (whether qualified or unqualified), both operands are compatible types.

Comment: Huh? You exactly cite the third case of the constraints. So constraints fulfilled, everythig is fine. The contraints apply before any later conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If "former" is "latter" are "pointer to object type" and "pointer to a void", then it means, after the conversion, the compare happens on two `void*`s,

Yes, that's certainly how I read it.

> which according to 6.5.9.2, is undefined:

No.  You quote section 6.5.9.2 of the standard, apparently in the belief that the case you are asking about is not covered by that section's enumerated list of alternatives, but you are mistaken.  This alternative covers the case:

> one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void;

It is important here to understand that a pointer to `void` *is* a pointer to an object type, for

> The `void` type  comprises  an  empty  set  of  values;  ***it  is  an  incomplete  object  type***  that cannot be completed.

(6.2.5/19; emphasis added)

6.5.9.2 should not be interpreted to suggest that `void` is not an object type; rather it says that `void *` is comparable to *all* object pointer types, including, of course, itself.

As @SouravGhosh observed first, this alternative also covers the case in question:

> both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types

for every type is compatible with itself (6.2.7/1).

Comment: Can you give an example of a "pointer to a non-object type"? Because I thought (and as pointed out by you, was wrong) that the only such type is `void*`.

Comment: No need to get that far actually. The constraints must be fullfilled **before** any conversion for the actual comparison. Bullet 3 of the constraints is exactly OPs starting point.

Comment: @user3528438, the distinction is between object pointers and function pointers.

Comment: @user3528438: As the answer clearly states: `void` **is** an object type, too. Being incomplete, you just cannot define variables of this type. Maybe you should read the definition of "object" in the C standard. It is not the same as for typical OOPL.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's where I'm mistaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I never thought from this angle, but my understanding is, two `void *`s are (after the conversion, as per the equality operator property) compatible type.

My reference is to

> "- both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;"

Comment: Two `void *` cannot be compatible types per se. Thus they are explicitly listed in the constraints.

Comment: @Olaf Sir, i'm confused. Considering `void` as an object type, why two pointers to `void` are not compatible type pointers? Sorry, if this is silly, but I am not getting it right now.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind (_I am pretty sure You would not :)_), is that the reason for DV? Otherwise, I'd like to have an explanation from whoever is the DV'r, , because a silent DV on a language-lawyer post is dangerous, it might be a sign of a serious misconception which needs to be rectified. :(

Comment: @Olaf also, why this happens specifically for `void`? Two pointers to `int` qualifies for the second bullet in 6.5.9.2, right? Then why don't two pointers to `void`?

Comment: Question is: are incomplete types compatible to each other? Resp. pointers to incomplete types. Sorry, I just had time to check the standard now and I did not find proof for my assumption (was very sure about that though). Still have a feeling they are not (that would automatically imply you cannot subtract two `void *` or compare otherwise than for equality), but without proof, I will dummy-edit the text to remove the DV.